# Im using jquery validation how do i display the errors in a seperate area

Tags: jquery, html, validation, webforms

I have a form that i am validating using jquery the validation plugin. What im trying to do is to have the errors displayed in a seperate div called "error" could anybody help me with this?

The form code is here:

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="/contactform/send_form_email.php">

           <label for="your_name">YOUR NAME</label>
           <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" class="fulltext"/>

           <label for="type">TYPE OF EVENT</label>
           <input type="text" name="type" id="type" class="fulltext"/>

           <label for="guests">GUESTS</label>
           <input type="text" name="guests" id="guests" class="shorttext"/>

           <label for="date">DATE</label>
           <input type="text"  name="date" id="date" class="shorttext"/>

           <label for="phone">PHONE</label>
           <input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone" class="shorttext"/>

           <label for="email">ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
           <input type="text" value="ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS" name="email" id="email" class="fulltext"/>
           <button type="submit" value="submit">go</button>
           </form>
```

and the JavaScript is here:

```
    rules: {
     email: { required: true, email: true,  maxlength: 50 },
     honeypot: { maxlength: 0 }
    }
  });
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The javascript code is not complete. The head of yours has beeing cut off.

Comment: Which jquery validation did you use ? http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+validation ^^

Comment: i used the http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate plugin mentioned here http://jquery.bassistance.de has two properties `errorContainer` and `errorPlacement` which you can use to place/display error at some other location on page. Here is a demo http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-methods-demo.html. View Source. If you are using same plugin, which I am sure you are using, it should be helpful. A submit handler is required to actually handle the submission of form. Please note the following code

```
$("#myform").validate({
 submitHandler: function(form) {
   // some other code
   // maybe disabling submit button
   // then:
   $(form).submit();//notice how form object is used, not the **id** of form is used here
   //^ if you dont take care, you will end up in too much recursion error
 }
});
```

Read this document, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation for more.

Comment: just one more question my form still seems to submit even with this code if i enter an email address it should require name and phone what an i missing? $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.example1").fancybox();
    $("#contactform").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#contactform div.error"),
    rules: {
        your_name: {required: true,  maxlength: 50},
        phone: {required: true,  maxlength: 50},
        email: { required: true, email: true,  maxlength: 50 },
        honeypot: { maxlength: 0 }
    }
});
      });

Comment: sorry i don't understand could you please expand on this?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment, I think your JS code is not correct, here is corrected code http://pastebin.com/8zjFxTSp

Comment: for some reason the only validation that seems to work is the email i don't see as to why this is the case could you shed any light on this matter

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [errorLabelContainer](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option:

```
$("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
        email: { required: true, email: true,  maxlength: 50 },
        honeypot: { maxlength: 0 }
    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#error",
    wrapper: "<div>"
});
```